# Cannot oversave model imagefield DJANGO

Tags: django

I'm encountering weird problem with updating image. I do not receive any error, it just doesn;t get saved to the MEDIA_ROOT folder. If I do it manually via admin_site it works. When i'm using the forms, the above happens.

views.py:

```
    @login_required
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass_change_form = UserUpdatePasswordForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        avatar_change_form = UserUpdateAvatar(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if pass_change_form.is_valid():
            pass_change_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'The password has been changed, please relogin')
            return redirect('profile')
        if avatar_change_form.is_valid():
            print(request.FILES)
            avatar_change_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'The avatar has been changed')
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Please fill the fields correctly')
            return redirect('password-change')
    else:
        pass_change_form = UserUpdatePasswordForm(user=request.user) 
        avatar_change_form = UserUpdateAvatar(instance=request.user.profile)
        context = {
            "pass":pass_change_form,
            "avatar":avatar_change_form
        }
        return render(request, 'users_templates/password_change.html', context)
```

forms:

```
class UserUpdateAvatar(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = ["avatar"]
```

models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_avatars")


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: Are you saving `pass_change_form` somewhere else in your view?

Comment: @IainShelvington yeah this actually works. It is responisble for password.

Comment: Can you share the whole view?

Comment: @IainShelvington added

Comment: If the `pass_change_form` is valid then you will never save the other form

Comment: @IainShelvington Just deleted the whole part with pass_change and nothing changed. Avatars still do not get saved.

Comment: Are you setting the correct mime type of your form? When you print request.FILES what do you get?

Comment: @IainShelvington I checked that before and all the time it returns empty dict. The form is displayed correctly and it allows me to choose the file from my pc so for sure I pass the file

Comment: You need to set the correct `enctype` on your form tag when uploading files - `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @IainShelvington wow that works ! :) Could you please explain me what was that ?

Comment: The `enctype` defines how the form data will be encoded in the HTTP request when sent to the server, the default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is basically the same as a querystring and only supports strings, "multipart/form-data" is a bit more complicated but it allows for entire files to be sent in the request